# Why can constexpr not apply to constructors?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, language-features, c++14

Why can constexpr not apply to constructors?

The following code cannot be compiled with VC++ 2013 CTP.

```
struct A
{
    constexpr A()
        : _n(5)
    {}

    int _n;
};

constexpr A f()
{
    return A();
}

int main()
{
    auto a = f();
}

error C3757: 'A': type not allowed for 'constexpr' function
```

Comment: I thought MSVC only supported non-member `constexpr` functions.

Comment: Basically because VC++ doesn't support it.

Comment: Indeed, that wouldn't be a problem for another compiler such as GCC.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VC 2013 does not support all C++11 features yet. Look at  [MSDN list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Comment: My compiler is VC++ 2013 CTP, rather than VC++ 2013.

Comment: According to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-the-visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp.aspx), the support of constexpr in 2013 CTP is "except for member functions".